# Passing arguments as void pointers to a function

Tags: c++, arguments, void-pointers

I got an array of functions to be called later as callbacks:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(void*)>> callbacks;
```

I do need to insert different kind of functions to this vector, that's why I choose void* to be the argument.

In one of these functions I needed an int, so I did like that:

```
void MyObject::MyTestCb(void* params) {
  int i = *(int*)params;
  ...
}

...

callbacks.push_back(std::bind(&MyObject::MyTestCb, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

When I call those callbacks, first I tried like this:

```
int index = 73;
void* params = (void*)&index;
callbacks[x](params);
```

But sometimes I wasn't received the value in the callback function! Most of the time were obtaining zero. May it is related due to being on a 64 bits machine?

Anyway, I tried this way then:

```
void* params = new int(73);
callbacks[x](params);
delete params;
```

And after some testing I didn't find any problem at all. However, is this last way the correct way to do it? Should it support any type as argument?

Comment: Both ways should work.  We need to see a [mcve] to explain why the first didn't.  (My best guess is that you have over-simplified, and that the local variable `index` no longer existed by the time you called the call-back.)

Comment: @MaxLanghof, fixed.

Comment: @MartinBonner _"Where do you see a mismatch?"_ In the first revision.

Comment: the correct way is not to use `void*`. Look at `std::function` when you need to store functions. Do the callbacks have all the same signature?

Comment: @user463035818: I use void* for the arguments, not for the functions. My callbacks has different signatures, all return void but they accept different parameters.

Comment: @Quedaro And how do you decide which function needs which arguments???

Comment: you really need to show some complete example. Indeed It does look like you need some form of type erasure and there are several good solutions available, using `void*` directly isnt really one of them

Comment: @Aconcagua I just hardcode them.

Comment: @Quedaro In other words: You know exactly which signature is needed for which index? Then drop the vector and have separate members: `std::function<void(int)> callback_for_event_0; std::function<void(unsigned long)> callback_for_event_1; std::function<void(std::string)> callback_for_event_2;`

Comment: @Quedaro If you want to be able to register more than one callback for the same event, you still can have vectors, but a separate one (with precise signature) for each event!